# How to make App available for beta tester in Testflight

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

This drives me crazy, I cannot find any information online, and the information I find are contradictory. The Apple Docs suck in this regard and I am hitting a dead end...
What do I want to accomplish? I have an iOS App which I want to make available to external beta testers.

So what I have found out so far is

1. Upload to Testflight
2. Get review for Beta testing
3. Add build to group

---

Step 1) Uploading

[image]

There are various ways to upload the build. Which one do I choose for external beta testing? I tried do find informatoion on each one of the possbilities, but did not find any. I went with 'Testflight Internal Only'.

Step 2) Get review for Beta testing
Apparently, before submitting an App to an external beta testing group, I need a beta app review. Where do I get this? How do I submit my app for beta testing review?!
After uploading I see my App here. But where to go from here? How to submit the App for beta testing review?

[image: screenshot appstore connect]

Step 3) Add build to group
Currently I am only able to add the build to the group of internal testers. Again, what do I need to do, step by step, in order to make the build for external testers available?

[image: another screenshot appstore connect]

Honestly, this drives me nuts... Why isnt there a clear step by step explanation from Apple?!

---

Edit: As you can see, I cannot add the current build (70) to the group external testers to trigger beta app review.

[image]

As you can see, it only "goes back" until build 64 (which could be the time I updated to XCode 15)

[image]

Comment: You have uploaded to TestFlight.  You have steps 2 and 3 the wrong way around.  You now need to assign the build to a group containing external testers, this will trigger the TestFlight review process.  Go into your "beta" group and add the desired build to the "Builds" section at the bottom of the screen

Comment: @Paulw11 I edited my q....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the "TestFlight and App Store" option when creating your build.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-your-app-for-beta-testing-and-releases):

> **TestFlight & App Store**
>
> Default settings to distribute through TestFlight and submit to the App Store. Use this option to update the build number of the content in your archive, perform automatic code signing, and upload your app with symbols.
>
> **TestFlight Internal Only**
>
> Default settings to distribute through TestFlight and *restrict access to your team*. Use this option to prevent a development build of your app from being submitted to the App Store.

Note the emphasis added - If you use the "TestFlight Internal Only" option then you can only distribute the build to your team.

The "TestFlight & App Store" option is the equivalent of the "App Store Connect" option in earlier versions of Xcode.

Once you have an appropriate build uploaded then you can add the build to your external group to trigger the TestFlight review process.

Comment: Thanks, from what is standing in the docs (I found that document as well) it is not clear that `TestFlight & App Store` makes it available to external testers. To me this sounds like "Publish your app in the app store and in TestFlight". Maye be latter could include availability for external testers... But I do not want to have it published yet.

Comment: It makes a build that can be made available to external testers or that can be submitted for app review. Nothing is going to end up in the App Store until you assign the build to your App Store record, submit it for review, get it approved and then decide to release it to the store. I think the new option you are using is to allow you to create builds that cannot be made available to people outside your team whether via TestFlight or through the App Store.